# Json.Net for serializing an object graph

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, json.net

I was using the .Net built in JavaScriptSerializer() to Serialize a JSON string coming from a webpage.
I heard that Newtonsoft.Json.Net have a better serializer, so I thought I would give it a try.

I load my json string, here is a sample.

```
jsonString = "{\"jName\":\"MB-CEF3-4\",\"StartDate\":\"08/20/2013 00:00\",\"EndDate\":\"08/29/2013 00:00\",\"JType\":\"General\",\"SetupParams\":[
{\"Name\":\"PTitle\",\"Title\":\"01. Period Title\",\"Type\":\"text\",\"Value\":\"TestName\"},
{\"Name\":\"PStart\",\"Title\":\"02. Period Start\",\"Type\":\"datetime\",\"Value\":\"08/20/2013\"},
{\"Name\":\"Target\",\"Title\":\"03. Target\",\"Type\":\"int\",\"Value\":\"1\"},
{\"Name\":\"URL\",\"Title\":\"04. Completion Report URL\",\"Type\":\"url\",\"Value\":\"http://www.example.com\"},
{\"Name\":\"FormTitle\",\"Title\":\"05. Form Title\",\"Type\":\"text\",\"Value\":\"ct\"},
{\"Name\":\"nvTypes\",\"Title\":\"{B6E71787-EB51-45CF-B408-552F79AF2E7B}\",\"Type\":\"nvc\",\"Value\":\"Use of nv tools\"},     {\"Name\":\"NVCoachingTypes\",\"Title\":\"\",\"Type\":\"nvc\",\"Value\":\"\"}]}";

JavaScriptSerializer scs = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Dictionary<String, Object> aps = (Dictionary<String, Object>)scs.DeserializeObject(ActSetupConfigs);
```

I then would pass this Dictionary into another worker class, where it is deserialized..

I was using:  var parameters = ((object[])Parameters["SetupParams"]);

and it would load the an array of objects.

I tried to do the same with Json.Net

```
Dictionary<String, Object> aps = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String, Object>>(ActSetupConfigs);
```

but when I try to deserialize it I don't get an array of objects, instead the sub collection of the array is just a string....so it throws an exception.  How can I use Json.net to serialize all the sub-collections?

Comment: Theres a great online tool to check for valid JSON.  Take your serialized json and run it through here, it will give you an idea whether your JSON is in correct format or not. http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sub-collection of the SetupParams array is not a string, it is a `JToken`, which is a generic container object that JSON.Net uses to hold a JSON structure.  Fortunately, it is easy to extract values from a JToken.  Try using this code instead.

```
JToken aps = JToken.Parse(jsonString);

foreach (JToken param in aps["SetupParams"])
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name:  " + param["Name"].Value<string>());
    Console.WriteLine("Title: " + param["Title"].Value<string>());
    Console.WriteLine("Type:  " + param["Type"].Value<string>());
    Console.WriteLine("Value: " + param["Value"].Value<string>());
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: The format can change....its dynamic...so I don't want to write classes which define everything

Comment: Updated my answer with another approach.

Comment: Yeah that works, I just got to move this team to Json.Net serialization without changing the existing code to much.  At the end of the day, usually all the objects in the Dictionary are strings, but in some cases a xml file can be posted as a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the above json response using json.net like,

```
dynamic initialresp=JValue.Parse(jsonString);
string jname=Convert.ToString(initialresp.jname);
...
...
dynamic setupparams=JArray.Parse(Convert.ToString(initialresp.SetupParams));
foreach(var item in setupparams)
{
string name=Convert.Tostring(item.Name);
string title=Convert.Tostring(item.Title);
...
...
}
```

Hope this helps.